# Using push_back() with range based for loops

Tags: c++, std, stdvector

Please excuse me if my understanding isn't up to par yet, Im still learning C++, and Im coming from an interpreted language (R).

My question is regarding the usage of vectors as index containers for range based `for` loops, In the following example :

```
//Declare 
std::vector<int> a{5,1,6,9} ;
std::vector<int> b{0,3} ;

//Reserve Memory
a.reserve(100) ;

//Loop & Modify
for(int i : b){
         a.push_back(a[i] + 400) ;
}
```

My question is, can this result in undefined behavior in some way?

Comment: Please ask one question per post.

Comment: Yes that will cause an error, you can look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules

Comment: `push.back(a[i] + 400) ;` is not a valid syntax.

Comment: `push.back(...)` is not valid. I think you meant `a.push_back(...)` or `b.push_back(...)`. Please [edit] to reflect your actual code.

Comment: You don't need the `temp` variable.

Comment: Right pardon me guys ive edited the question

Comment: There is no UB in this code. As long as you don't change container that you are iterating over, it will be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as `b` contains valid indexes into `a` your code is perfectly fine.

A problem would arise if you would modify the container your iterating over with range for, e.g. this would be invalid:

```
for (auto e : a)
{
    a.push_back(...);
}
```

But you are not doing this so you are OK.